# how to save form template in database built by formbuilder

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-plugins, formbuilder

I am using https://formbuilder.online/ on my site to make the form from form builder jquery plugin and I want to save form template in the database

I add form builder plugin successfully http://pro1.wealthbyhealth.in/formbuilder/demo.php

How can i save the form template in the database?

Comment: it's interesting.... What if from the template we need to create the same table structure on mysql (database) ?

Answer (score 2):

We actually have the same problem and mine is still unanswered. But I know a way that might help you.

In order to save the form template in mysql database, you should create a table with the fields like this one >>

[Table Fields screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlFq9.png)

And when the user save the form it will be saved in the database like this >>

[Sample Text Input screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tn757.png)

Now, when it comes to retrieving the "form template" that we saved a while ago. You can use if else statements in php. For example,

```
if(type == "text"){
  statement that you will create a text input here
} else if (type == "password"){
  statement that you will create a password input here
}
```

And so on...

Tell me if that helps

Comment: i think we need to traverse from the form template and create the table structure accordingly... what do you think, @Elliot?